# How to locate buffer position in .emacs

Tags: emacs

For example, with `emacs --debug-init`, I got this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error:(invalid-read-syntax ")")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer *load*> nil "/home/wilbeibi/.emacs" nil t);   Reading at buffer position 9220
```

The question is: How to solve the problem each time I got the error explanation like "Reading at buffer position XXXX". How to jump to that position?

BTW,To this specific problem, the things I did:
1. use 'C-M-e' to check each function.
2. Replace any Chinese `）` with `)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
M-x goto-char
```

Help:

`goto-char` is an interactive built-in function in `C source code'.

It is bound to `<menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <go-to-pos>.`

(goto-char POSITION)

Set point to POSITION, a number or marker.
Beginning of buffer is position (point-min), end is (point-max).

The return value is POSITION.

Comment: It is also bound to `M-g c`, at least on my computer.